# How to fetch local JSON data from Rails e.g bookings.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all very noob question.

I'm trying to store data in a react calendar but it needs to store it using JSON.

I've noticed that when you scaffold, rails automatically also gives you a JSON version.

In my case - http://localhost:3000/users/1/bookings.json

Which returns `[{"first_name":"Fake Name","booking_time":"2019-04-22T02:03:00.000Z","pick_up_time":"2019-04-22T02:03:00.000Z"}]` in JSON.

I know how to fetch JSON data from a external URL and parse it through however all these external URL's are public whereas in my case the bookings are private.

Is there a way for me to fetch from bookings.json and store it in a variable and also by making it private where I wouldn't need to publicise it?

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def dashboard
  @lookup_booking = ???("/users/1/bookings.json")???
  end
end
```

React dashboard

```
<%= react_component("Booking", { booking: @lookup_booking})%>
```

Comment: If you really want the users already as json on a variable you can use `@lookup_booking = User.find(1).bookings.to_json`. But I don't thinks it's a good idea, just assign `@lookup_booking = User.find(1).bookings` and turn it into json on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a local request to the Bookings JSON endpoint the same way you'd make any external request - using something like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) might work:

```rb
@lookup_booking = HTTParty.get(user_bookings_url(1))
```

But this won't be authenticated, so it'll need the same authentication as any other request.

It's a little weird to do it this way unless whatever is generating the bookings is a separate service, or if you want it to be one. If you're going to be using one codebase, you might want to do something similar to what [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod) suggested in the comments, and simply share the code.

You could break the `BookingsController` code into an [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) or a module, or a [Service Object](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/service-objects-explained-simply-for-ruby-on-rails-5-a8cc42a5441f)  (or, more simply, a method on the `User` class) and that would then allow you to cleanly share the code between the `BookingsController` and `HomeController`. It might look something like this:

```rb
# app/services/lookup_user_bookings.rb
class LookupUserBookings 
  def self.bookings_as_json(user_id)
    # complicated logic to find user bookings goes here...
    bookings.as_json
  end
end

# bookings_controller.rb
class BookingsController
  def index
    @bookings = LookupUserBookings.bookings_as_json(current_user)
    render json: @bookings
  end
end

# home_controller
class HomeController
  def dashboard
    @bookings = LookupUserBookings.bookings_as_json(current_user)
  end
end

# dashboard.html.erb

<%= react_component("Booking", { booking: @bookings.to_json })%>
```